# Permutations and cycles in integers

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

I am interested in the integers between $100$ and $1000$ who are divisible by $6$. This problem is solvable. However if we add the following restriction the problem will be more complicated. Now we will only count the integers between $100$ and $1000$ who are divisible by 6 and exist of different numbers from the set $\{1, ..., 9\}$. For example, the integers $126$ and $612$ are the same.

How many integers are left between $100$ and $1000$?

Comment: Do you mean that $126$ and $612$ together count for one only?

Comment: Yes that is right! Only integers with different numbers counts. And $0$'s are not allowed.

Comment: And how about $666$? A possibility but with equal (not different) digits?

Comment: Correct, we do not count 666.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

The question is equivalent to this problem.

Choose three integers such that sum of these is dibisible by three and at least one of them is even.

Comment: Can you give some more explanation about 'at least one of them is even'. I do not see why this is true.

Comment: @iJup: Since a number is divisible by $6$ if it is even and divisible by $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I am wrong.

The sum of the numbers in the integer between $100$ and $1000$ has to be $0$ mod $3$.
We divide the set $\{1, ..., 9\}$ into $3$ different cosets.

- A = $\{3;6;9\}$ - $0$ mod $3$
- B = $\{1;4;7\}$ - $1$ mod $3$
- C = $\{2;5;8\}$ - $2$ mod $3$

Possibilities are:

- $0 + 0 +0$ - 1 possibility (936)
- $1 + 1 +1$ - 1 possibility (714)
- $2 + 2 +2$ - 1 possibility (528)
- $0 + 1 +2$ - ends on a $2, 4, 6, 8$ will all bring $3 \cdot 3$ possibilities.

Total number of possibilities is $4 \cdot 9 + 3 \cdot 1$.

However it seems that we are still counting the same integer combinations. For example 648, 864 and 486. Finally we will count 35 integers.